# Should non-sibilant fricatives be treated like plosives or fricatives?

Tags: phonology

I don't like ending my words with plosives, because my native language tends to not audibly pronounce them. I prefer to stick to fricatives and nasals for codas. However, I'm unsure where non-sibilant fricatives should go. Do they undergo de-voicing in codas like plosives do? I've seen auxlang guides recommend to keep coda consonants limited to fricatives, nasals, and 'liquids', but such guides normally don't recommend you use rare phones like non-sibilant fricatives. Maybe I should just play it safe and treat them like plosives, keeping them limited to onsets?

Comment: Do you mean treated like plosives or _sibilant_ fricatives in the title? Non-sibilant fricatives are, by definition, fricatives.

Comment: Though the fact that you call them "rare phones" might mean you mean something other than sounds like `[f]`.

Comment: The only phones I've ever seen called non-sibilant fricatives are θ and ð. I used to see them as plosives before I looked them up for the first time. i was weirded out that they were classified as fricatives. To me, a fricative is a consonant where you can hold it indefinitely, unlike stops which can't be held (outside of nasals anyway). Essentially, if you can germinate it and its not a nasal, its a fricative.

Comment: The term for a consonant you can hold indefinitely is a "continuant", and all fricatives do fall into that category—including the two you mentioned. I can easily hold them for at least ten seconds each. But there are some dialects of English that have turned them into stops; I suspect you might speak one of those? (Or perhaps your native language isn't English?)

Comment: In natlangs that devoice final consonants, as far as I know, the rule applies to all fricatives as well as stops.  But that is a separate question from whether or not you ‘ought’ to allow this or that consonant in coda.  – Can't you hold [θ]? I can.

Comment: No, I cannot. Like I said, I was taken off-guard when I first found out all those years ago that it was a fricative.

Comment: @user8600 can you let us know your native dialect of English (or your native language if it is not English)? As others have said, there is no phonetic reason [θ] or [ð] cannot be held indefinitely (or at least until you run out of breath), but it's entirely possible you don't pronounce the phonemes represented /θ/ & /ð/ as [θ] & [ð]. It's important to note that the representation of these phonemes is based on their pronunciation in the standard GA and RP varieties and there are plenty of other varieties that do pronounce them as stops (notably Caribbean, Irish, & Indian English)

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, but I've had speech problems my whole life. When I was taking speech therapy courses in elementary school, the teacher taught us to pronounce 'th' by 'biting our tongue then yanking it back'. Both the voiceless and voiced variants somehow got interpretted as allophones in my brain. The reason I've been thinking about them is because I'm trying to teach myself finally to hear the distinction. The same teacher btw taught us to do a retroflex L rather than an alveolar L and it wasn't until I started studying linguistics that I discovered this.

Comment: these stopped pronunciations of /θ/ & /ð/ may or may not be distinct from /t/ & /d/. Caribbean English speakers generally merge them together. Indian English speakers generally have /θ/ & /ð/ as dental stops and /t/ & /d/ as retroflex stops. Irish speakers vary, with some having /θ/ & /ð/ as dental stops and /t/ & /d/ as alveolar stops (possibly palatalised) but many (most?) pronouncing both sets as dental stops

Comment: it sounds like you may have learnt affricates [t̪͡θ ] & [d̪͡ð]. As an affricate includes a stop part this explains why you can't produce them indefinitely. Affricates often pattern with stops, but can also pattern fricatives so you can go either way

Comment: I had no idea those even existed. So I'm not even pronouncing θ and ð? And here I am trying to put them into a conlang. Fml. Guess I need to remove them then, and forget about learning the distinction (at least for the time being). Fml and fuck that quark speech therapist that taught me to mis-pronounce my own native language. Who knows what else I'm doing wrong? I was in that class all 6 years of elementary school!

Comment: for any place of articulation with both stops and fricatives you can have an affricate (occasionally clusters of stop and fricative at different places of articulation are analysed as non-homorganic affricates, but this is unusual). As for the speech therapist, it is a very difficult business teaching people to produce specific phones and many of the distinctions made are extremely fine making them difficult to communicate, especially to children

Comment: with that in mind, and noting that it is generally more important for speech to be understandable (something that depends to a large extent on speech being consistent) than for it to have the same phonetics as the standard, it may make more sense for a speech therapist teaching someone to distinguish e.g. /θ/ from /t/ to focus on teaching a consistent distinction between [t̪͡θ ] & [t] rather than focussing on the precise pronunciation of /θ/ as [θ] which may take longer to teach to the same degree of consistency

Comment: Either way, I guess my answer is these phones I thought they were should be treated like other fricatives. Mine though need to be treated like affricates. Guess that's my answer. Fml still. Am I cursed to only make conlangs that sound like Toki Pona or a romlang just because of my own speech problems?

Answer (score 0):

Why do people post comments for rather than answers? This has been answered and I don't see much that can be added to it.

The answer is I've been accidentally pronouncing my non-sibilant fricatives as affricates, thus my confusion over whether they're more akin to plosives or fricatives. Either I need to just treat them like affricates, or learn the proper fricatives. That's my answer.